# Visibility for password numbers

Tags: web, console, numbers, passwords, password-protection

Just created my first marketplace online and I want to make it more secure.
Users can sign in with a password with 4 chosen digits. If I hit inspect element and change the type="password" to type="text" the password (The numbers are revealed)

On this website I found as an example I can't change the type of the id="digit-2" via the console.

```
<input id="digit-2" maxlength="2" size="1" type="password" value="3">
```

[image]

There is always this error:
[image]

Why is that the case and can I change or at least find the right Id of the input field to change the type from

```
type ="password"
```

to

```
type = "text"
```

in the console?

Thanks!

Comment: How does the ability the type of the input in a particular visitor's browser make it more or less secure?

Answer (score 1):

## First, the JS side of things:

The real reason you aren't able to change the `type` field on that element is because `digit-1` would appear to the JavaScript interpreter as an attempt to subtract `1` from the value in some variable called `digit`.

Additionally, the "unexpected token" error occurs because the interpreter sees `1.` and assumes that what follows should be decimal digits for the number, so when it sees `type` immediately after it isn't sure what to do.

This can be summed up by saying: you can't have dashes in keywords / variable names. A dash looks to the interpreter like an attempt to subtract.

If you were to use a different method of retrieving the element, such as `document.getElementById("digit-1")`, you would find that you'd be perfectly able to change the type.

## Now, the security side:

There's something more important to address here: *the ability to alter visibility of these numbers has nothing to do with security.* After all, the user knows their own password, and is in control of their own browser. If you are handling passwords, there are much more relevant considerations. To name a few:

- Ensure that the passwords are sufficiently complex that they cannot be brute-forced (four digits, for example, isn't necessarily the best idea. [Four random words, or truly random data, are a far better choice](https://fractionalciso.com/correct-horse-battery-staple-review/))
- Ensure you **do not store passwords**, but rather appropriately salt and hash them for server-side storage. [See this article for some more details](https://auth0.com/blog/hashing-passwords-one-way-road-to-security/)
- Ensure that you use a secure method of sending the passwords to your server, such as HTTPS.